# previous class selector is working even after updating the class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having a div with class `abc`. There is a jQuery function which selects that div using its class and make ajax request. Now when ajax function is successfully returned, i've changed the class so that the ajax method should not get called again until its a div of class `abc`.
But what happens is that even after updating the class of the div to `xyz` the same ajax function is called again.

```
success: function(data){
                    //updating the class here
                    $(self).addClass('xyz').removeClass('abc');
                }
```

I can see in the source that the class is updated but still the same attribute selector selects the earlier class and runs the ajax method again. Is there some other way to do what i am trying to do? Please Help! Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
$('.up_arrow').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(event) {

        var resid = $(this).attr('name');

        var post_data = {
            'resid' : resid,
            '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
        };

        var self = this;

        if(resid){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/ci_theyaw/restaurants/plusrepo",
                data: post_data,
                success: function(data){
                    //console.log($(this).siblings('.rep_count').text());
                    $(self).addClass('up_arrowed').removeClass('up_arrow');
                    $(self).css('background-position','0 40px');
                    $(self).next('.rep_count').html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is the complete function which does the job. Here the class to be updated is `up_arrow` -> `up_arrowed` and the selector for the function is `up_arrow`. but after updating it executes anyway.

Comment: You need to show where the ajax is actually called, including any selectors used to trigger it

Comment: If you've attached the event directly to the element, it won't be removed even if the original criteria for selecting it won't apply anymore. That's the best guess without seeing the code.

Comment: can you tell the indirect way to attach the event?

Comment: $('.up_arrow').click(function (event) { ... }); no need to use each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.up_arrow').each(function() {
```

What happens here is that jQuery looks for all elements that have the class `up_arrow` *at this moment* and attaches the event to those elements directly. After that the class doesn't matter anymore even if it changes.

If you use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.up_arrow', function(event) {
    var resid = $(this).attr('name');
    // etc
```

...now the `.up_arrow` selector is evaluated *at the time when the user clicks on the page* instead of when the code is first executed. You can also change `document` to a common static element that contains all the `.up_arrow` elements.

---

Unrelated side note: *If* you use `.click()` in other situations (in this case you *can't* use it) you don't need to use `.each()` with a simple click handler; just do `$('.selector').click(function() {`. It will apply to each element automatically.

Comment: using `$('.selector').click(function() {` will do the work or should i use `on()` instead?

Comment: No, that was completely unrelated to the problem. It does exactly what you have now. You have to use `.on()`.

Comment: Ok, Trying that. Anyways thanks for help. Hope that should work :)

Comment: Simply put, You are awesome!