# Class selector works even after removing class

Tags: jquery

I have a live class selector (**on**) which should work on elements with **numberonly** class and removes non-numeric values from field. It does not stop working even when I remove the **numberonly** class from element:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".numberonly").on("input propertychange paste",function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
  });
});
  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myfield").removeClass("numberonly");  
})
```

```css
input {width:300px;max-width:100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This input should accept non-numeric values<br>because I removed class "numberonly":<br><br>
<input id="myfield" class="numberonly">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because events are attached on DOM element and not on selectors. You should rather add if condition in click event to check whether element have class in it or not:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".numberonly").on("input propertychange paste",function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('numberonly'))
       $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".numberonly").on("input propertychange paste",function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('numberonly'))
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
});
});
  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myfield").removeClass("numberonly");  
})
```

```css
input {width:300px;max-width:100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This input should accept non-numeric values<br>because I removed class "numberonly":<br><br>
<input id="myfield" class="numberonly">
```

Comment: No. Dom ready event should be there. It ensures loading of all elements

Comment: Is this Q/A wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294100/previous-class-selector-is-working-even-after-updating-the-class

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Wrong in what way? It does show a slightly better way of doing this, yes.

Comment: Sorry I noticed in that Q/A the selector is defined on document not class. @JJJ

Comment: @AliSheikhpour You might find that there are almost always more than one way to do the same thing, without one being more or less wrong than the other. The other answer doesn't trigger the event at all when the class is missing so it's slightly (but unnoticeably) more efficient.